# Is there any way to move the docker running target disk to a specific disk

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm setting up my own project on a server using docker. OS have installed on the hard-disk and docker too and because of that i get into problem to use disk. I read/write with a high speed on the disk so hard disk can't provide what i need. I plugged SSD to my server and moved the swap and ramdisk location to the SSD device.

Docker: latest
CentOS: 7

Now i need to run docker on the SSD device, not on hard-disk.

Is there any way to change move it to the SSD device to increase the read/write speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stop the docker service.

Option 1:

Change /etc/docker/daemon.json according to the official page: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options

You would add something like:

```
{
    "data-root": "/your/new/path",
    "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

Option 2:

You need to locate the file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and open it for edit.

You need to change the line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://` into:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /your/new/path -H unix://
```

Common for both options:

Copy your files into the new location:

```
rsync -aqxP /var/lib/docker/ /your/new/path/
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome. which of the 2 options did you choose?